# Get value from materialize autocomplete with chips

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, materialize

Please help me, I want to get data from MaterializeCSS chips selected, but I don't know, how.
I want value form input (type:hidden) contains id data from chips.

```js
var my_data = {
  "0":"Apple",
  "1":"Microsoft",
  "2":"Google"
}

var myConvertedData = {};
$.each(my_data, function(index, value) {
  myConvertedData[value] = null;
});
$('.chips-autocomplete').material_chip({
  autocompleteData: myConvertedData
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class=" col s12">
  <form method="POST" action="#">
    <div class="chips chips-autocomplete" id="optionS"></div>
    <input class="browser-default" type="text" name="val_selected" placeholder="form hidden for get item selected #options">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large" disabled>Save
    </button>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my code : [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/riza24/xznnkgww/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**PS :** **I'm not using JQuery here since it is no longer a dependency.**

### I have a similar issue too. This will replace value of hidden input and you can send the data to backend with phpform. You can implement this prototype:

**JS:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("Genre").value = null; //making sure value is nulled when the browser hits back button and gets back to this page.
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.chips');
    var chips_genre = M.Chips.init(elems, {
        autocompleteOptions: {
            data: {
                'Romance': null, //Your Pickers
                'Action': null,
                'Adventure': null,
                'Comedy': null,
                'Crime': null,
                'Drama': null,
                'Fantasy': null,
                'Historical': null,
                'Fiction': null,
                'Mystery': null,
                'Thriller': null,
                'Satire': null,
                'Science Fiction': null,
            },
            limit: 5,
            minLength: 1 //customise this value according to your requirement
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("add_btn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        chips_genre.forEach(function(entry) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(entry.chipsData));
            var dat = entry.chipsData;
            dat.forEach(function (tags){
                document.getElementById("Genre").value += tags.tag + ","; //using "," as delimiter for multiple tags
            });
            document.getElementById("Genre").value += null; //adding null to the end.
        });
    });
});
```

**Form:**

```
<div class="chips chips-genre input-field">
    <input class="white-text" id="Genre_field">
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="Genre" name="Genre_Field">
<button type="submit" id="add_btn" class="btn">ADD</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean with "id data" but I had same problem and now solved and pass autocomplete chips to another pass with POST method (works also with GET method).

This is my HTML form (target code, form is very long):

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <input type="text" name="shadow_alb_arts"  id="shadow_alb_arts" value="">
</div>
<div class="chips chips-arts chips-placeholder input-field col s12" id="par_alb_arts">
    <input type="text" id="album_artists" name="album_artists[]">
</div>
```

The input `#shadow_alb_arts` will contain ID Artist that I will pass with POST (because `#album_artists` is passed blank), with jQuery I'll concat all Artist IDs with delimiter.

This textarea will be hidden so final user will not see that input, in code is visible to test and see result.

This is jQuery code:

```
$('.chips-arts').chips(
        {
            autocompleteOptions: {
                data: {
                    //<?php echo implode(",\n", $arts); ?>
                    // Your data, I'll use this string format: artist_id) Artist Name (start_year-end_year) from country_name
                },
                limit: Infinity,
                minLength: 1,
            },
            placeholder: 'Artist name',
            secondaryPlaceholder: '+ Artist',
            onChipAdd: function(e) {
                var final_ids = "";
                $( "#par_alb_arts > div.chip" ).each(function() {
                    var chip_selected = $(this).text();
                    var author = $.trim(chip_selected);
                    var id_author = " " + author.split(")")[0] + " ";
                    final_ids = final_ids + id_author;
                });
                $("#shadow_alb_arts").val(final_ids);
            }
        },
    );
});
```

To be clear:

`onChipAdd: function(e)` we will enter when user select a chip autocompleted value (is `onChipAdd` and not `onChipSelect` because when user select a value (or press enter) will be added new chip).

`var final_ids = "";` is the final string where all ID Arts selected are stored

`$( "#par_alb_arts > div.chip" ).each(function()` this is jQuery foreach with child selection (parent > child), when onChipAdd occur new div will be create with class `chip`, in this case I'll get text from chip tag and parse the string (all values inside autocomplete section are using specific pattern because later I'll read text and get correctly the ID)

`$("#shadow_alb_arts").val(final_ids);` re-write the input text filed (hidden) with Artist IDs, when final user submit form this text input will contains values.